# Using Clock-Widget in a Fragment possible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-widget

I have a Fragment in my MainActivity, that displays a Digital Clock. It works: It shows the current system time. But it looks rather simple. So before I start trying to style this clock I wanted to ask, if there is a way, to use the systems Digital-Clock Widget?

Screenshot of the widget, that I'd like to use in my Fragment:

[image]

FragmentClock.java:

```
public class FragmentClock extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clock, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

fragment_clock.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutClockDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">
    <DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digital_clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```